# Time plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, datetime

I tried to plot this type of data

```
x        y
00:00    99.42
00:15    99.44
00:30    99.41
00:45    99.37
01:00    99.00
01:15    99.29
01:30    99.51
01:45    99.58
02:00    99.49
02:15    99.50
02:30    99.52
02:45    99.57
03:00    99.56
```

with `pgfplots`. But the package cannot read the time data properly.
Is there a way to plot the time format?

Comment: Here is one example : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2982/who-wants-to-win-a-latex-book :)

Comment: It seems you need to add a date before (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18540/19156) and configure the input format

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/pgfplots-data-time-format

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @tk112: Did the answers at the linked questions help you? If not, could you edit your question to provide a complete minimal example document?

Comment: With no response, I'm marking as a dupe: flag if this is wrong.