# Tick labels in pgfplots data time format

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

I tried to plot a data set containing seconds and milliseconds with pgfplots.
I’ve found a solution for my task here ([pgfplots data time format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/pgfplots-data-time-format)), which I changed a bit. This principally works very well.
My code goes here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\def\transformtime#1:#2:#3!{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60+#3}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    timeplot zero/.initial=0,
    timeplot/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{##1-floor((##1)/60)*60}
            \def\pgfmathresult{\pgfmathprintnumber{\hours}:\pgfmathprintnumber{\minutes}:\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill]{\seconds}}
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    scaled y ticks=false,
    yticklabel=\tick
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0, grid=major, grid style=dashed, ytick={00:12:00, 00:13:00, 00:14:00},
]
\addplot table {
State           Time  
-13 00:12:42.40
-12 00:12:57.06
-11 00:13:17.59
-10 00:13:40.83
-9  00:14:07.44
-8  00:14:31.11
-7  00:14:04.28
-6  00:14:12.07
-5  00:14:09.27
-4  00:13:59.92
-3  00:13:56.82
-2  00:13:55.17
-1  00:13:53.52
0   00:13:52.47
1   00:13:59.32
2   00:14:00.58
3   00:13:43.12
4   00:13:49.05
5   00:13:28.63
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem now is that I get odd tick labels (both 12:60 and 14:0.00 is not I was expecting...):

[image]

I found a similar question ([Date plot using pgfplots with odd tick label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18540/date-plot-using-pgfplots-with-odd-tick-label)), but with that solution I unfortunately do not know how to solve my problem. 
Could anyone here give me a hint?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The `12:60` is obviously wrong, but I'm not sure what you were expecting instead of the `14:0.00`. Do you want that to print as `14:00`?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer 14:00.00.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one attempt, where I've added some conditional code to add the leading zero if the number is less than 10. The idea is like this (for the minutes part):

```
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\minutes<10,0,)}\pgfmathresult\pgfmathprintnumber{\minutes}:%
```

The `\pgfmathparse` will store either `0` or an empty string depending on whether a leading zero is required (determined by testing if `\minutes` is less than 10). This is then dumped into the `\def` of the top-level `\pgfmathresult` by invoking `\pgfmathresult` inside the group, which is followed by the `\pgfmathprintnumber` for the number of minutes itself.

Unfortunately I was not really able to solve the `12:60` rounding issue. I thought maybe defining `\seconds`, `\minutes`, and `\hours` from the bottom up rather than the top down would help, but that caused issues elsewhere.

But: disabling the FPU makes it correct with no detrimental effects, because `pgfplots` does its own scaling to avoid "Dimension too large" errors. So it may or may not be an acceptable solution for you.

I also changed the options for the printing of `\seconds`:

```
\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill]{\seconds}%
```

Adding `fixed` "locks in" fixed mode so scientific notation is never used, and the `fixed zerofill` will always be respected (since we're always in `fixed` mode).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\def\transformtime#1:#2:#3!{
%    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60+#3}
%    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    timeplot zero/.initial=0,
    timeplot/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={%
%            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{##1-floor((##1)/60)*60}
            \def\pgfmathresult{%
              \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(  \hours<10,0,)}\pgfmathresult\pgfmathprintnumber{\hours}:%
              \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\minutes<10,0,)}\pgfmathresult\pgfmathprintnumber{\minutes}:%
              \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\seconds<10,0,)}\pgfmathresult\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill]{\seconds}%
            }
%            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    scaled y ticks=false,
    yticklabel=\tick
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0, ytick={00:11:30.056, 00:12:00, 00:13:00, 00:14:00},
]
\addplot table {
State           Time  
-13 00:12:42.40
-12 00:12:57.06
-11 00:13:17.59
-10 00:13:40.83
-9  00:14:07.44
-8  00:14:31.11
-7  00:14:04.28
-6  00:14:12.07
-5  00:14:09.27
-4  00:13:59.92
-3  00:13:56.82
-2  00:13:55.17
-1  00:13:53.52
0   00:13:52.47
1   00:13:59.32
2   00:14:00.58
3   00:13:43.12
4   00:13:49.05
5   00:13:28.63
7   00:11:15.6256432
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]