# Date/Time in both axes with PGFPLOT

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, dateplot

I am trying to plot some data that contains date/time values in both the x and y axis.

I have been using the pgfplots and have managed to plot date/times on the x axis and on the y axis separately using both \usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot} and a custom \plotset{.....} (seen on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149964/tick-labels-in-pgfplots-data-time-format) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79252/pgfplots-data-time-format))

However, I have been unsuccessful to combine date/time on both axis on the same graph.

**Can you please advice how to approach this issue?**

My attempt data looks as follows:

```
TIMESTAMP, TIMEDELAY
2015-08-02 06:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 06:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 07:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 07:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 08:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 08:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 09:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 09:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 10:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 10:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 11:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 11:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 12:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 12:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 13:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 13:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 14:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 14:30, 00:04
2015-08-02 15:00, 
2015-08-02 15:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 16:00, 00:07
2015-08-02 16:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 17:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 17:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 18:00, 00:03
```

With blank data points (e.g.15:00)

My successful attempt to ploting timestamps on the Y axis

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\def\transformtime#1:#2!{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    timeplot zero/.initial=0,
    timeplot/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\seconds{##1-floor((##1)/60)*60}
            \def\pgfmathresult{\pgfmathprintnumber{\hours}:\pgfmathprintnumber{\minutes}:\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill]{\seconds}}
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    scaled y ticks=false,
    yticklabel=\tick
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0, grid=major, grid style=dashed, ,
]
\addplot table {
State           Time  
6 00:03
6.5 00:02
7 00:03
7.5 00:03
8 00:03
8.5 00:03
9 00:04
9.5 00:02
10 00:03
10.5 00:03
11 00:03
11.5 00:03
12 00:04
12.5 00:03
13 00:03
13.5 00:03
14 00:04
14.5 00:04
15 00:03
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And my successful attempt at plotting time on the X axis. (Although I am forced to use a csv file when using dateplot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pagestyle{empty}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[date coordinates in=x,]
\addplot table[col sep=comma] {datedata2.csv};;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. Could you please provide a minimal working example of what you have tried?

Comment: Do you want to have a the TIMESTAMP on the x -axis and the TIMEDELAY on the y-axis?

Comment: Sergej, thanks! To your first question I added my attempts. To your second question, yes

Comment: Is the TIMEDELAY format hours:minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

The blank data point is still an issue.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\def\transformtime#1:#2!{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1*3600-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}*3600+#2*60}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    timeplot zero/.initial=0,
    timeplot/.style={
        y coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed,}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\hours{floor(##1/3600)+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero}}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\minutes{floor((##1-(\hours - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/timeplot zero})*3600)/60)}
            \def\pgfmathresult{
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\hours}:%
                \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\minutes,60))/100}%
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[skip 0.=true, dec sep={}, fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
                }
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
        scaled y ticks=false,
        yticklabel=\tick
    }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datedata2.csv}
TIMESTAMP, TIMEDELAY
2015-08-02 06:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 06:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 07:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 07:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 08:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 08:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 09:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 09:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 10:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 10:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 11:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 11:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 12:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 12:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 13:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 13:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 14:00, 00:04
2015-08-02 14:30, 00:04
%2015-08-02 15:00, nan
2015-08-02 15:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 16:00, 00:07
2015-08-02 16:30, 00:02
2015-08-02 17:00, 00:03
2015-08-02 17:30, 00:03
2015-08-02 18:00, 00:03
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    timeplot, timeplot zero=0, grid=major, grid style=dashed,
    date coordinates in=x,
    x tick label style={align=center, rotate=45, font=\scriptsize},
    ]
    \addplot table[col sep=comma] {datedata2.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! I will try working around the blank point!